# The meaning of $G^H$ in group theory and/or field theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

**Quick question:**

I've seen this notation in group theory and in Galois theory: $G^H$.

I don't know what it means, but I've seen it in a similar way and it's confusing. An example will be in this [page from the Inverse Galois problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem) where it says *A simple example: cyclic groups*, the second paragraph.

Specifically, it says something like this:

> The fundamental theorem of Galois theory implies that the corresponding fixed field, $F = \mathbb{Q}(μ)^H$, has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb {Q}$. By taking appropriate sums of conjugates of $\mu$, following the construction of Gaussian periods, one can find an element $\alpha$ of $F$ that generates $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and compute its minimal polynomial.

What does it mean for the $\mathbb{Q}(μ)^H$ part? Or more generally $G^H$ (whatever that is)?

Comment: If $G$ is a subgroup of the automorphism group of the field $K$, then $K^G:=\{x\in K: g(x)=x \text{for any}\ g\in G \}$. In general, if $M$ is an abelian group with a group action by the group $G$, (which is equivalent to say that $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module,) $M^G:=\{m\in M: gm=m \text{for any}\ g\in G\}$.

Comment: Thank you!! This is very helpful! However, when you say the subgroup of the automorphism group, you mean that $K \le \text{Aut}(H)$, i.e., that $K$ is a subgroup of the group commented above (group of all automorphism of some group $H$)?

Comment: This means the set of elements of $G$ fixed by the action of $H$

Comment: @JoshuaOrtiz In my notations, $K$ is a field, and $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(K)$ (different from your notations in the question). Following your notations in the question, my $K$ will be your $F$, and my $G$ will be your $H$.